# Remember password and selected item in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

I created login Page and put 4 controls on it. 
(2 textboxes for username and password & one button for submit & one `dropdownlist`)
I Use below code to remember password in coockie and it's work:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
```

also i want to remember my dropdownlist selected item by user .
how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set cookie:

```
Response.Cookies["DropDown"].Value = MyDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;
```

and on page load get cookie:

```
if(Request.Cookies["DropDown"]!=null)
{
    var valueFromCookie = Request.Cookies["DropDown"].Value;
}
```